# Листинг исходного текста программы с помощью github?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github

Здравствуйте! У меня есть программа на github.
Нужно (желательно автоматически и быстро) сделать полный листинг исходного кода в формате html или odt, pdf для подачи заявки в патентное бюро.
Можно ли это сделать при помощи самого github?

Comment: Написал скрипт для Python, который решает эту задачу без github. Как наберу 50 "чатлов", выложу его здесь.

Comment: Можно просто открыть гуглдокс, создать новый текстовый документ, зайти в меню "дополнения" (или как он там в русской версии называется?) и установить дополнение "Code pretty". Теперь будет достаточно скопировать код (просто, с редактора), вставить в документ, выделить его и вызвать дополнение с меню. Все будет отформатировано и разукрашено. Сохранить потом в вордовский формат очень просто.

P.S. Я не понимаю патентов на код. Это бред.
P.S.S. @abalckin - Исправьте причинно-следственную связь:)

Comment: У меня в проекте 30 файлов, что, все копировать\вставлять? А если я завтра код исправлю, что, опять все заново? Или старательно выискивать исправления и синхронизировать листинг?
P.S.
А когда я говорил о патенте на код? Код управляет работой системы, на которую получается патент. А на код можно оформить авторское свидетельство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой ответ - никак. Можно использовать дополнительный скрипт, например такой

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import os
from subprocess import call
def get_filepaths(directory):
    """
    This function will generate the file names in a directory 
    tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each 
    directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), 
    it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).
    """
    file_paths = []  # List which will store all of the full filepaths.

    # Walk the tree.
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        files = [f for f in files if not f[0] == '.' and not f == 'getlisting.py']
        directories[:] = [d for d in directories if not d[0] == '.']
        for filename in files:
            # Join the two strings in order to form the full filepath.
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(filepath)
            if fileExtension=='.py' or fileExtension=='.ui':
                file_paths.append(filepath)  # Add it to the list.

    return file_paths  # Self-explanatory.

files = get_filepaths(".")
listing = open("listing.tex","w", encoding='cp1251')
listing.write(r"""\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{cmap}""")
listing.write(r"""
\usepackage{listings}             % Include the listings-package
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
""")
listing.write(r"""\usepackage[left=2cm, top=2cm, right=0.5cm, bottom=20mm,""")
listing.write(r"""nohead, nofoot]{geometry}
""")
listing.write(r"""
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Оглавление}
\begin{document}
""")
listing.write(r"""
\begin{titlepage}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

\center % Center everything on the page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\textsc{\LARGE Национальная Академия Наук}\\[1.5cm] % Name of your university/college
\textsc{\Large Институт Автоматики и Информационных Технологий}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name
\textsc{\large Лаборатория}\\[3cm] % Minor heading such as course title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Листинг исходного текста}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
{ \huge \bfseries программных средств}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AUTHOR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and remove the section above
\Large \emph{Автор:}\\
с.н.с. И.И. \textsc{Иванов}\\[3cm] % Your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LOGO SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\includegraphics{./logo.png}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DATE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

{\large \today}\\[3cm] % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise
\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace
\end{titlepage}
""")
listing.write(r"""
\tableofcontents
\clearpage""")
listing.write(r"""
\section{Исходный код исполнимых файлов на языке Python}
""")
for f in files:
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(f)
    if fileExtension == '.py':
        listing.write(r"""
    \subsection{\protect\url{"""+f+"""}}
""")
        listing.write(r"\lstinputlisting[language=Python, breaklines=true]")
        listing.write(r"{"+f+"}")
        listing.write("\n")

listing.write(r"""
\section{Исходный код графического интерфейса пользователя на языке XML}
""")
for f in files:
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(f)
    if fileExtension == '.ui':
        listing.write(r"""
    \subsection{\protect\url{"""+f+"""}}
""")
        listing.write(
            r"\lstinputlisting[language=XML, breaklines=true]")
        listing.write(r"{"+f+"}")
        listing.write("\n")
listing.write(r"""
\end{document}""")
listing.close()
call(["pdflatex", "listing.tex"])
```